# How to Redirect Page in getitems in antd fremwork in reactjs

Tags: redirect, antd

i have antd sidebar used javasript code for this and in that sidbar  have menu and submenus so i want to redirect that sub menu page  for example in sidebar i have menu for user and in that menu i have submenu like login logout profile so if i click on login then login page should display but don't know how

i expect mainainable and less line code suggestion because there are to many pages that i have to reder i can not give onclick event to everyone so i tried this code :-- function getItem(label, key, icon, children, type, path) {
return {
key,
icon,
children: path ? {children} : children,
label,
type,
};
}

const items = [
getItem(
"MAIN",
"mn",
null,
[
getItem(
"Dashboard",
"1",



),

```
  getItem(
    "Masters",
    "sub2",
    <div className="icon-div">
      <img src={masterimg} alt="master" className="icon" />
    </div>,
    [
      getItem("Truck Master", "2", null, null, null, 'truck-master'),
      getItem("Driver Master", "3"),
      getItem("Location Master", "4"),
      getItem("Trailer", "5"),
    ]
  ),
```

facing runtime error :- (list || []).map is not a function
TypeError: (list || []).map is not a function